# Coding multiple-row graphs (looping) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm sure there is a fairly simple answer to this question but I've been pulling my hair out for multiple days trying to figure this out and no one in my department works with VBA enough to know.
I'm new to automating graphs but I have a project where I need to make almost 800 graphs! The data itself is fairly straightforward, with 4 variables (columns): County, City, Store Type, and Number of Employees:

```
COUNTY  CITY    STORE TYPE  NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES
X   A   1   100
X   A   2   100
X   A   3   100
X   A   4   100
X   B   1   100
X   B   2   100
X   B   3   100
X   B   4   100
```

I need to make bar graphs for each County/City combination with the Store Type as the X-values and the Number of Employees displayed on the Y-axis. This is super easy to do in VBA:

```
Sub makegraph2()
Range("A2:D5").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Employees per Store Type"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Employees per Store 
Type"
End Sub
```

Rather than copying/pasting the same graph and reselecting the data for each 4 rows downward, I'm trying to find a way to automate it with a loop. I've tried doing this myself (testing with only 50 rows ((A2:D50 represents all 4 columns and 50 rows)) so not to get 800 graphs that are wrong and crash my computer) using offset in many different ways. My most resent attempt produces a graph with all 50 rows on it at once:

```
Sub makegraph()
Dim Row As Integer

For Row = 1 To 50
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!A2:D50").Offset(4, 0)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Employees by Store Type"
Next Row
End Sub
```

Before that, I made separate graphs but they were all of the same data (would not go down 4 rows to graph the next set). So clearly I'm using Offset and Range wrong, but I can't figure out how...

Any help is so appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: Is it always 4 rows per combination?

Comment: Yes! Some Y-values are 0 (no employees), but always 4 rows for the store type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Taylor! Have you tried Pivot Charts? You can use filters in Pivot Charts to cut down a lot of the work here. Here's a link to a tutorial with more information - [Link](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/pivot-chart.html).

Comment: Hello! Yes, I've used Pivot Charts, but only for dynamic data sets of single tables--I'll look into it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but try this:

```
Sub makegraph()

    Dim i As Long, co, cht As Chart '<<edit here
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 1 To 50
        Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
        'position and size the chart here by setting the
        '  Top/Left/Width/Height properties
        With co.Chart
            'calculate the required offset
            .SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("A2:D5").Offset((i - 1) * 4, 0)
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Employees by Store Type"
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this, but I kept getting a "type mismatch" error for the line Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)

Comment: I edited the declaration for `co` to remove `As ChartObject` -  that should fix it

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub makegraph()
Dim Row As Integer

For Row = 1 To 50
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!A2:D50").Offset(4, 0)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Employees by Store Type"
Next Row
End Sub
```

from what I understand by this code. the offset you apply is always from the same spot which is Range("Sheet!A2:D50") secondly you have specified the whole area as the source.

I would suggest doing more absolute values or make a variable for the range:

example of variable range:

```
Sub makegraph()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Area As Range

    Set Area = Range("A2:D5")

    For Row = 1 To 50
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Area
        Set Area = Area.Offset(4, 0)
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Employees by Store Type"
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Example of Absolute values:

```
Sub makegraph()
    Dim Row As Integer

    For Row = 2 To 50 Step 4
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row + 3, 1))
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Employees by Store Type"
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoting for great use of the [Step](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/step-keyword.html) Keyword! I will definitely be making use of this. Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you! The variable range makes the most sense to me, but I keep getting a "Object variable or With block variable not set" for the line Area = Range("Sheet1!A2:D5") not sure why :(

Comment: And using absolute values, I keep getting a mismatch error for the line "ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!A" + Row + ":D" + (Row + 3))" related to using "Row" which I also don't understand...

Comment: Oh sorry if you ever get 'the object variable or with block' error you need to use set: set Area = Range()

Comment: I have edited the examples to make sure they work. Im sorry they didn't as I did them from the top of my head